# Node.js tutorial, Http Server handling errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I am following node.js tutorials on learnyounode, the "HTTP CLIENT" section. The code that is proposed as solution is:

```
var http = require('http')

http.get(process.argv[2], function (response) {
  response.setEncoding('utf8')
  response.on('data', console.log)
  response.on('error', console.error)
})
```

but executing this with node gives me

```
events.js:72
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

my working solution is this one:

```
var http = require('http')

http.get(process.argv[2], function (response) {
  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  response.on('data', console.log);     
}).on('error', console.error);
```

that means that the Object response is not a http.ClientRequest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, response is [http.ServerResponse](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) while request is [http.ClientRequest](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest). As the docs say, `error` event is emitted on request object, not response one.